# Junit test with WireMock throws 404 not found expection

Tags: java, spring, api, junit, wiremock

I had this problem since a week, I didn't found enough resources.
I have a java application which consume an external API, I want to test my application using wiremock.

When I want to send a file it's always shown 404 Not found.
I found that the issue is that wiremock not preserving the Host header value, so I have this code below, but it always doesn't work.

I tried the real API and it's working perfectly using WireMock Record & Playback feature, but I specify the -preserve-host-header option(without this it's getting 404 Not Found)

My service that I want to test (I don't have controllers):

```
@Service
public class Bank{
    //This method is working
    public String hello(String hello){
        return exernalAPI.get("hello").toString(); // It's just an example
    }
    //This method is not working in test(404)
    public void uploadFile(String inputStrum...){
       //The code here is used to send the file to an external API using method post
    }
}
```

I did a record and Playback to capture the request and the response from the real extern API,

Class test:

```
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port=0)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={Bank.class})
public class BankTest{

@Autowired
public Bank bank;
@Test //The test is passing
public void helloTest(){
    String expected = resourse.getResource("classpath:response/helloMessage.txt").toString(); //Get the captured response
    String actual = bank.hello("Jack"); //this return Hi Jack and it's working
    assertEquals(expected,actual);
}
@Test //This test is not passing
public String uploadFileTest(){
     InputSteam is = getInputStream();
     //code to get inputStream 
     Resource expected= resourse.getResourse("classpath:responses/upload_response.json");
     String expected = expected.toString();

     is.setContent(resource.getResource("classpath:file_to_upload.zip"));

     String actual = bank.uploadFile(is); // Here i have 404 not found
     assertEquals(expected,actual);

}
```

after several searches I found that I have to preserve the Host header using something like this :

```
preserveHostHeader(true);
```

Comment: Are you saying that it is working once you use the preserve host header option?

Comment: Just the recording using the standalone jar which is working when i use host header option